# Need help printing a 2d array using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, data-structures, graph

I have to print out the adjacency matrix of the graph (2d array) in main, the array is named **edges** and made using pointers on the TransportGraph.cpp file.I tried to loop through the size, but it returns an error. what did I do wrong?

**Main.cpp :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "TransportGraph.h"
#include "TransportGraph.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TransportGraphType<string> newGraph;
    //adding vertexes
    string dh= "Dhaka", ran="Rangpur", raj="Rajshahi", my = "Mymensingh", sy="Sylhet", ch="Chittagong", br="Barisal", kh= "Khulna";
    newGraph.AddVertex(dh);
    newGraph.AddVertex(ran);
    //added all the other relevant vertexes

    //adding edges with weight 1 as they are undirected.

    newGraph.AddEdge(dh,raj,1);
    newGraph.AddEdge(raj,dh,1);
    //added the rest similarly, it is a bidirectional graph

    //my attempt at printing out the adjacency matrix:

    for (int i=0;j<newGraph.edges.size();i++){
        cout<<newGraph.edges[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

**The TransportGraph.cpp file: (it has the edges array and the other relevant methods)**

```
#include "TransportGraph.h"
#include "stacktype.cpp"
#include "quetype.cpp"
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    const int NULL_EDGE = 0;
    template<class VertexType>
    TransportGraphType<VertexType>::TransportGraphType()
    {
    numVertices = 0;
    maxVertices = 50;
    vertices = new VertexType[50];
    edges = new int*[50];
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
    edges[i] = new int [50];
    marks = new bool[50];
    }
    template<class VertexType>
    TransportGraphType<VertexType>::TransportGraphType(int maxV)
    {
    numVertices = 0;
    maxVertices = maxV;
    vertices = new VertexType[maxV];
    edges = new int*[maxV];
    for(int i=0;i<maxV;i++)
    edges[i] = new int [maxV];
    marks = new bool[maxV];
    }
    template<class VertexType>
    TransportGraphType<VertexType>::~TransportGraphType()
    {
    delete [] vertices;
    delete [] marks;
    for(int i=0;i<maxVertices;i++)
    delete [] edges[i];
    delete [] edges;
    }
//has other AddVertex and AddEdge methods, also BFS DFS methods
```

**TransportGraph.h file (Holds the methods in a class):**

```
#ifndef TRANSPORTGRAPH_H_INCLUDED
#define TRANSPORTGRAPH_H_INCLUDED
#include "stacktype.h"
#include "quetype.h"
template<class VertexType>

class TransportGraphType{


    public:
    TransportGraphType();
    TransportGraphType(int maxV);
    ~TransportGraphType();
    void MakeEmpty();
    bool IsEmpty();
    bool IsFull();
    void AddVertex(VertexType);
    void AddEdge(VertexType,VertexType, int);
    int WeightIs(VertexType,VertexType);
    void GetToVertices(VertexType,QueType<VertexType>&);
    void ClearMarks();
    void MarkVertex(VertexType);
    bool IsMarked(VertexType);
    void DepthFirstSearch(VertexType,VertexType);
    void BreadthFirstSearch(VertexType,VertexType);
    private:
    int numVertices;
    int maxVertices;
    VertexType* vertices;
    int **edges;
    bool* marks;


};



#endif // TRANSPORTGRAPH_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: The error is |error: request for member 'size' in 'newGraph.TransportGraphType<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >: when edges in public. when edges in private, it just says it is private.

Comment: `edges` is a pointer. There is no `.size()` method to call on it. Instead, use `std::vector` and `std::string` to make this easier.

Comment: We are instructed to use the given libraries, so any way I could manipulate the pointer and print it as a 2d array? The final output being the adjacent matrix?